Correct shape and structure of Input Data for Autoencoder
i am trying to build my first Autoencoder for anomaly detection and i dont really know, how the Input Data has to be shaped in order to train the Model. I`ll give you Information about the Data and i hope someone can help me out:

Context: The Data is buffer-data. Its obtained from our university at a stamping process.
Each recorded instance shape (22000, 64), where the 22000 represents the Spectra and 64 the Frequency-Bands. So, when i plot this with plt.imshow(), i get a colourful spectral image of one buffer-data. Each of the 64 frequency bands can be lineplotted.
I have 1000 of these Buffer data and my array of all data is shaped like this (1000, 22000, 64)


When i fit the model, do i just use the tensor/array of all data?
Any insightful resources would be appreciated for autoencoders and anomaly detection

Thanks.

Hi@bungeegum,To train an Autoencoder for anomaly detection using spectral data,Input Data Shape and Preprocessing
Data Shape Understanding:
Each instance of your data is represented as a 2D array of shape (22000, 64).
You have 1000 such instances, resulting in an overall array shape of (1000, 22000, 64).
Training Input for Autoencoder:
For training the Autoencoder, you typically feed it with the entire dataset array. In your case, this would be the tensor/array of shape (1000, 22000, 64).

Data Preparation Steps:
Normalization: Normalize your data to bring all features to a similar scale. This helps the model converge faster during training. You can use sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler or MinMaxScaler for this purpose.
